# Why can I not unregister my UpdatePanel when it was not registered with the ScriptManager?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, radgrid

I am using the modal pop up in the code below. I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'updatePnl' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager. This might occur if the UpdatePanel was removed from the control tree and later added again, which is not supported.
Parameter name: updatePanel
```

What could be causing this?

Here is my code:

```
<telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="20%" HeaderText="See Your Assessment">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button CommandName="Show" OnClick="grdMasterbtnClick" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("SurveyClientID")%>'
                            ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Your Assessment" />
                        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender CancelControlID="btnCancel" PopupControlID="modelPopUp" ID="ModalPopupExtender1"
                            runat="server" TargetControlID="imgClientFreeEval">
                        </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnl" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:Panel ID="modelPopUp" runat="server" Visible="false" BackColor="AliceBlue">
                                    <p>
                                        These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?
                                    </p>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnOk" Text="OK" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" />
                                </asp:Panel>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20%"></HeaderStyle>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727658/cannot-unregister-updatepanel-with-id-xxx-since-it-was-not-registered-with-th

Comment: It might be best to move the update panel to be outside of the GridTemplateColumn.  Since it's in an ItemTemplate, you'll be repeating it's creation a lot.  If you move it outside, you'll only have one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cannot unregister UpdatePanel with ID 'xxx' since it was not registered with the ScriptManager... " in RadGrid while editing record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727658/cannot-unregister-updatepanel-with-id-xxx-since-it-was-not-registered-with-th)